# How can resolve this error : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: ggplot2, runtime-error

p<- ggplot(cherry, aes(x=Color, y=SSC, group=Row.size, color=Row.size)) +

```
geom_line() +
```

geom_point()+

geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=SSC-sd, ymax=SSC+sd), width=.2,

position=position_dodge(0.05))

> p

Error in SSC - sd : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Hello, I am trying to make a ggplot graph but I am getting this error. I researched but unfortunately I could not find any information. Please help me. Thank you!!

Comment: From the error message I guess that `sd` is not a variable in your dataset. If you want sd to be the standard deviation of variable SSC try `geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=SSC-sd(SSC), ymax=SSC+sd(SSC)), width=.2, position=position_dodge(0.05))`.

Comment: To be honest, it worked but all line looks so messy and it does not show to error bars

Answer (score 0):

As stefan mentioned it is because you have not defined sd in your dataset and from your results as you describe them in your answer, I suspect that you haven't summerized your data. [Here's](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/#Helper%20functions) a good description of the function summarySE that summerises the data for you so you can plot them.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Attaching links is great, but it is better to add the core logic from it to the answer.